firebase_auth/app-verification-failed - The app verification process has failed
I have a flutter project that I'm running on my IOS simulator, and It's integrated to Firebase.
When I try to use this function:
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: countryDial +
        numberController.text.trim(),
    verificationCompleted:
        (PhoneAuthCredential
            credential) async {
      showSnackBarText(
          'Code Confirmed', context);

      setState(() {
        isCodeSending = false;
      });
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithCredential(credential);
      userLocation =
          await MyPrefer.getUserLocation();
      await userCheck()
          ? CallApi().updateUserData.add({
              'name': '',
              'secondName': '',
              'email': '',
              'status': 'active',
              'calledItem': [],
              'phoneNumber': FirebaseAuth
                  .instance
                  .currentUser!
                  .phoneNumber,
              'userId': FirebaseAuth
                  .instance.currentUser!.uid,
              'location': userLocation,
            })
          : Container();

      if (widget.isEditPhone == true) {
        CallApi()
            .updateUserData
            .doc(widget.userId)
            .update({
          'phoneNumber': countryDial +
              numberController.text.trim(),
        });
      }
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context) =>
                      MyBottomTab(
                        tabNum: 3,
                      )),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    },
    verificationFailed:
        (FirebaseAuthException e) {
      setState(() {
        isCodeSending = false;
      });
      if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
        showSnackBarText(
            'Wrong phone number, Try Again!',
            context);
      }
      if (e.code == 'too-many-requests') {
        showSnackBarText(
            'Too many requests, try again later!',
            context);
      } else {
        showSnackBarText(
            'Something Wrong',
            context);
        debugPrint(
            'Phone verification error: $e');
        Sentry.captureException(e);
      }
    },
    codeSent: (String verificationID,
        int? resendToken) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MessagePage(
            isEditNumber: widget.isEditPhone,
            userId: widget.userId,
            phoneNumber: countryDial +
                numberController.text.trim(),
            verificationId: verificationID,
          ),
        ),
      );
      showSnackBarText(
          'Code Sent', context);
      setState(() {
        token = resendToken!;
        isCodeSending = false;
      });
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout:
        (String verificationID) {
      // showSnackBarText(
      //     'Code Expired', context);
    },
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60));
}

I get the following error:
Phone verification error: [firebase_auth/app-verification-failed] The app verification process has failed

I couldn't find anyone writing about this failure code firebase_auth/app-verification-failed

The following is the pubspecs.yaml details: sdk: ">=2.16.0-134.1.beta <3.0.0"

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
flutter_svg: ^2.0.1
firebase_core: ^2.5.0
firebase_database: ^10.0.2
image_picker: ^0.8.6+1
cloud_firestore: ^4.7.0
firebase_storage: ^11.0.6
carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
firebase_auth: ^4.5.0
shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
step_progress_indicator: ^1.0.2
firebase_remote_config: ^3.0.10
webview_flutter: ^4.2.0
flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.2+3
permission_handler: ^10.2.0
url_launcher: ^6.1.11
flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3
flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
sentry_flutter: ^7.5.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.6.4
intl: ^0.18.0
share_plus: ^4.5.3
firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.2.0
package_info: ^2.0.2
photo_view: ^0.14.0
country_picker: ^2.0.20
cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
firebase_app_check: ^0.1.5+1
http: ^1.1.0


Do you have app attestation enabled on the Firebase side?   If so, have you uploaded the required keys?
